# Ant 1.8.0 + delete task does not delete broken symbolic link

Tags: ant

Any ideas why this does not remove the broken symlink itself?

```
<delete removeNotFollowedSymlinks="true">
    <fileset followsymlinks="false" file="/some/path/to/broken/symlink" />
</delete>
```

Alternatively I could use the below, but I'd prefer to avoid exec?

```
<exec executable="rm">
  <arg value="-f"/>
  <arg value="/some/path/to/broken/symlink" />
</exec>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the real way to do it...

```
<symlink failonerror="false" action="delete" link="/some/path/to/broken/symlink" />
```

Comment: FWIW, this doesn't work for me on OS X 10.6 with Ant 1.7.1, and it's really annoying. I had to resort to <exec> with /bin/rm to remove a symlink. You'd think they might have fixed this long ago.